# How do I apply padding to a div without affecting center alignment?

Tags: html, css

Very simple test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Weird Centering Demo</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body
            {
                margin: 0px;
            }

            .test1
            {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #acf;
            }

            .test2
            {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #aaf;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='test1'>Test 1</div>
        <div class='test2'>Test 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both of the divs in the page above should be centering the text they contain. However, somehow increasing the padding for Test 1 moves its text to the right. When inspecting this in the chrome developer tools, it appears the 100px padding applies on the left and not the right. I'm having trouble understanding this asymmetrical behaviour and am not having any luck experimenting with setting padding-left and padding-right individually either.

What's the idiomatic way to apply padding without changing centered text alignment?

Comment: Probably because of the 100% width... have you tried setting a fixed width? Or, at least, something below 100% (try 90% for example). It's not a good idea to mix variable sizes along with fixed ones, in my opinion...

Comment: But I want it to be 100% width. Otherwise the color will not fill the width of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding padding to the left and/or right increases the width of the block box containing your `div`.

If you set the width to 100%, the computed width will be wider than the page and cause
and overflow condition.

If the content is overflowing, then it will not be centered, but left justified.

You may be able to fix the problem by adding the property `box-sizing: border-box` 
which will contain the padding to within the edges of the block box.

However, the best solution depends a bit on the details of your design.

You can read more about box-sizing at: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.test1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #acf;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.test2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaf;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='test1'>Test 1</div>
<div class='test2'>Test 2</div>
```

Comment: So is there a way to specify the width of an element including its padding? I just want a div to fill the available width and move the content away from its outer edges.

Comment: Also +1 for a solution which gives the right behaviour. I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way though since we're still pushing the div to more than the size of its container by applying padding, but then it gets squashed in... I guess.

Comment: If you apply the `box-sizing: border-box` CSS property, then you will get your `div` with the width that you need that also takes into account the padding.  Your second comment (idomatic way comment) alludes to how CSS implemented the box model.  Internet Explorer used to apply the padding within the edges of the element box, whereas other browsers increased the box width to make room for the padding.  As of CSS3, `box-sizing` gave you the ability to control the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You have one adding 10px, but the other is adding 100px.

Since the widths are both at 100% and the padding is different then the one will have text that is off center from the other as one is going further [in width] than the other.

You fix it by having both at the same width (primary) and/or same padding (secondary).

Take an interactive and fun learning course at http://www.codeacademy.com: Quick link to css box model (if the link works for you): http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-6merh/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b